# Save NSWindow Size on Resize & Close For User

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder, resize, nswindow

I've noticed that all applications on OS X seem to save the size you set it at. The next time you open it it's typically in the same position and size.

I'm making an app and I've noticed that after resizing, if I launch the application again it's just the size of what I've set in Xcode 4's IB and not the size that I resized it to on launch.

Do I have to manually save the window size each time its changed? Or is there an easier way to do this through IB? (My window does have a minimum size set if that changes anything.)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Apple makes it easy. In interface builder, for your window, just type in a unique name in the `Autosave` field and it will save it under that name in the global user defaults. E.G.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I assumed there was a simple solution but just couldn't figure it out.

Comment: I add a link to my own answer for us Visual Studio for Mac users: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66347693/2287576

Answer (score 5):

When you select your main window in the Interface Builder, there should be a property called `Autosave` in the attributes inspector. Put any name in there does the trick for me.

Answer (score 5):

After setting the **`Autosave`** name in IB I could see that my window's frame was being saved to its preferences file, but still the auto restore would not work. Then I remembered to uncheck the **`Close windows when quitting an app`** checkbox in the **System Preferences** under the **General** settings, and the window position restored as expected.

Answer (score 3):

If you did not use IB to create your window, you can set this property in Swift using:

```
setFrameAutosaveName(_ name: NSWindow.FrameAutosaveName)
```

(the `frameAutosaveName` property is `get` only)

For example:

```
windowController.window?.setFrameAutosaveName("appWindow")
```