# Remember window position with Xamarin Forms Mac OS

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin.forms, window, positioning

I understand that XCode supports AutoSave for remembering window position. I see it freely documented.

What about Xamarin Forms 5, when the platform is macOS?

This is some of my code, if it helps:

```
public class AppDelegate : FormsApplicationDelegate
{
    NSWindow window;
    public AppDelegate()
    {
        var style = NSWindowStyle.Closable | NSWindowStyle.Resizable | NSWindowStyle.Titled;

        var rect = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(200, 1000, 1024, 768);
        window = new NSWindow(rect, style, NSBackingStore.Buffered, false)
        {
            Title = "Elderly and Infirm Rota",
            TitleVisibility = NSWindowTitleVisibility.Visible
        };

        InstallApplicationFiles();
    }
```

---

#### Update

In the comments I also referred to *limiting the size* of the window. I have now worked out that bit ([`NSWindow.MinSize`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419206-minsize)):

```
NSWindow window;
public AppDelegate()
{
    var style = NSWindowStyle.Closable | NSWindowStyle.Resizable | NSWindowStyle.Titled;

    var rect = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(200, 1000, 1024, 768);
    window = new NSWindow(rect, style, NSBackingStore.Buffered, false)
    {
        Title = "Elderly and Infirm Rota",
        TitleVisibility = NSWindowTitleVisibility.Visible,
        MinSize = rect.Size
    };

    InstallApplicationFiles();
}
```

Now I have to address the window size / position and remembering it.

Comment: Forms itself won't do it, but you should be able to use the Mac API from a custom renderer or dependency service to do it

Comment: @Jason I have used neither of those features. I will have to try and find a good tutorial for both.

Comment: @Jason I see this but it does cover macOS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/contentpage

Comment: I am still struggling with this. Also applicable is the minimum allowed window size.

Comment: you haven't posted any code or provided any detail about what you're trying to do or which APIs you're using

Comment: @Jason That is because I don't really know which part of this we are looking at. I have included the Main.CS contents from the MacOS project. I don't know if this was the code needed.

Comment: @Jason Put simply - remember the window position and state (and in addition, limit the minimum window size)

Comment: "I understand that XCode supports AutoSave" - I assume this means you have done some research and identified the relevant APIs needed to support this feature.

Comment: @Jason I can't find that link now. But I did find this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004151 but it is on about NSWindow and I don't even know if this is the right path I should be taking to resolve this.

Comment: @Jason I made some progress (updated question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was not too hard. Visual Studio for Mac is missing some settings (I think) that are described for Xcode. See: [`frameAutoSaveName`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419362-frameautosavename)

The answers provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115280/save-nswindow-size-on-resize-close-for-user) were also useful. Part of the problem for me was having the right terms to search for an answer and in this case `NSWindow` was important.

In my macOS `AppDeletegate` constructor I now do this:

```
public AppDelegate()
{
    var style = NSWindowStyle.Closable | NSWindowStyle.Resizable | NSWindowStyle.Titled;

    var rect = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(200, 1000, 1024, 768);
    window = new NSWindow(rect, style, NSBackingStore.Buffered, false)
    {
        Title = NSBundle.MainBundle.ObjectForInfoDictionary("CFBundleDisplayName").ToString(),
        TitleVisibility = NSWindowTitleVisibility.Visible,
        MinSize = rect.Size,
        FrameAutosaveName = "xxxxx"
    };

    InstallApplicationFiles();
}
```

Notice the additional setting of the `FrameAutosaveName` property:

```
FrameAutosaveName = "xxxxx"
```

Now the window position is remembers when I close the application.

---

Please let me know if there was a way to set this directly in Visual Studio for Mac GUI.